# Format String to NSString in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set up tableViewCell properties to different Labels. However i keep getting errors regarding the Strings. I've started by hooking the array up like this.

```
 cell.titleViewLabel.text = arrayNews[indexPath.row].title
```

However i keep getting this error

```
cannot assign a value of type nsstring to a value of type string
```

How can i format the above title to a NSString so i don't get this error in cellForRowAtIndexPath? or this due to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The root of the problem is as follows:

`cell.titleViewLabel.text` is `NSString`

`arrayNews[indexPath.row].title` is `string`

**Solution:**

You need to cast your `string` to `NSString`. Try the following syntax

```
cell.titleViewLabel.text = arrayNews[indexPath.row].title as NSString
```

Comment: I think you have the `NSString` and `String` backwards.